# How can I see which flags Nginx was compiled with?

Tags: nginx

How can I check what modules have been added to an nginx installation?

Comment: Another way of saying this is "how can I see which flags Nginx was compiled with?" Just wanted to add that to increase searchability.

Answer (score 310):

`nginx -V` will list all the configured modules. There is no explicit enable/load command.

Comment: **Note for noobs:** If not logged in as root user, the command would be `sudo nginx -V`

Comment: I did not need to use `sudo` on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please note that this parameter is case sensitive. If you use lower case "-v" you will get only version number. Upper case "-V" gives you complete configuration including list of all modules used for compiling Nginx binary.

Comment: [It seems](//serverfault.com/a/870609/110020) like some systems may not have the `$PATH` set properly for non-superusers, omitting all the `sbin` directories, so, you might have to specify the full path of the daemon (e.g., `/usr/sbin/nginx -V`), or indeed just use [`sudo`](http://ports.su/security/sudo).

Comment: @its_me ...you probably don't need sudo to run `nginx -V`

Answer (score 73):

Diff-able one-liner:

```
2>&1 nginx -V | tr -- - '\n' | grep _module
```

Convenient for comparing two environments:

```
lsmodn="2>&1 nginx -V | tr -- - '\n' | grep _module"
diff -y <(ssh www-prd eval $lsmodn) <(ssh www-qa eval $lsmodn)
```

***EDIT:***

Thank you, Roman Newaza, for correctly pointing out that this includes `--without` module compile flags. I'm not using `--without` flags and was just focused on getting the module list, so I didn't catch that; the one-liner can be modified to help diff compile flags between 2 installations, like this:

```
2>&1 nginx -V | tr ' '  '\n'
```

which is the same as:

```
2>&1 nginx -V | xargs -n1
```

Maybe also pipe that through `sort` to normalize idiosyncratic ordering of compile flags and `tr` again to split assignments onto diff-able lines. Final result:

```
lsmodn="2>&1 nginx -V | xargs -n1 | sort | tr = '\n'"
diff -y <(ssh www-prd eval $lsmodn) <(ssh www-qa eval $lsmodn)
```

That works if `sort` behaves the same on both remote hosts (ie. they are both GNU or BSD). If you are comparing Linux to BSD (Mac OS X), just move the `| sort | tr = '\n'` piece out of `lsmodn` to the local shell where `sort` will be consistent:

```
lsmodn="2>&1 nginx -V | xargs -n1"
diff -y <(ssh linux eval $lsmodn | sort | tr = '\n') <(ssh macosx eval $lsmodn  | sort | tr = '\n')
```

Messier, but it works.

Comment: `2>&1 nginx -V | tr -- - '\n' | grep _module` command is totally wrong as it lists without-* options as installed!

Comment: awesome answer. out of interest why do you put 2>&1 in front. from what I've seen thats more unusual?

Comment: @MattTagg it's only in front until it's used. Then it's at the end of either command.

Answer (score 7):

`nginx -V` doesn't show all modules, it shows about 20 modules for me.

I use `strings /usr/sbin/nginx|grep _module|grep -v configure| sort` which lists all 200+ modules in my nginx.

I also tried `objdump` but looks like the nginx in my installation had the binary stripped.

Comment: This really helps me, and is the only one right answer. `nginx -V` can't get the build in modules.

Answer (score 4):

- The `nginx -V` command (upper-case V) will list all the modules, as well as other compile-time options:

  `%nginx -V 
  nginx version: nginx/1.2.2
  built by gcc 4.2.1 20070719 
  TLS SNI support enabled 
  configure arguments: --prefix=/var/www --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-log-path=logs/access.log --error-log-path=logs/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/www/cache/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/www/cache/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/www/cache/fastcgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/www/cache/scgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/www/cache/uwsgi_temp --user=www --group=www --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-ipv6 --without-mail_pop3_module --without-mail_imap_module --without-mail_smtp_module
  %`

  Note that there is never any need for [`sudo`](http://ports.su/security/sudo) for this command, as superuser powers would only be needed by nginx for opening ports below [`IPPORT_RESERVED` (e.g., ports below 1024)](http://bxr.su/o/sys/netinet/in.h#IPPORT_RESERVED) and/or certain log-files for writing.

  However, depending on your `$PATH` settings, you may either need to specify the full path — e.g., `/usr/sbin/nginx -V`, or indeed use `sudo` for having the appropriate `/sbin/` directory be included in the `$PATH`.
- Starting with newer nginx releases — since `nginx 1.9.11` (February 2016) — [dynamically loadable modules are now supported](http://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-dynamic-modules-how-they-work/), too — http://nginx.org/r/load_module — with the help of the `load_module` directive.