# How to add nginx file upload module to Debian Squeeze?

Tags: nginx, debian

I need to use nginx upload module in my Debian Squeeze server.
I already have installed nginx and nginx-extras. the nginx version is 1.4.2. 
From the [package description](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/nginx-extras) of nginx-extras, it seems that upload module should be included however nginx -V gives me this list:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.2
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: 
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx 
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock 
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid 
--with-pcre-jit 
--with-debug 
--with-file-aio 
--with-http_addition_module 
--with-http_dav_module 
--with-http_flv_module 
--with-http_geoip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_image_filter_module 
--with-http_mp4_module 
--with-http_perl_module 
--with-http_random_index_module 
--with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_secure_link_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_xslt_module 
--with-ipv6 
--with-mail 
--with-mail_ssl_module 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-echo 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/ngx-fancyindex 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-push-stream-module 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-lua 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-syslog 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/ngx_http_pinba_module 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/ngx_pagespeed 
--add-module=/usr/src/nginx/source/nginx-1.4.2/debian/modules/nginx-x-rid-header 
--with-ld-opt=-lossp-uuid
```

which does not include upload module. [This listing](http://www.cambus.net/nginx-packages-in-debian-stable/) also confirms that upload module should be in squeeze nginx-extras since nginx 1.2.1.

I tried to re-package nginx from source and configure with upload module using [this guide](https://coderwall.com/p/drhh8w), but got error while compiling. I also installed the Wheezy packages by adding repos to /etc/apt/sources.list but they also did not contain upload module.

I hesitate to build nginx from source so I'm really have no other idea and appreciate your hints.

P.S.

```
 dpkg --list | grep -i nginx
ii  nginx-common                        1.4.2-1~dotdeb.0             small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-extras     

               1.4.2-1~dotdeb.0             nginx web/proxy server (extended version)


$dpkg --listfiles nginx-extras
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/lib/perl5/auto
/usr/lib/perl5/auto/nginx
/usr/lib/perl5/auto/nginx/nginx.bs
/usr/lib/perl5/auto/nginx/nginx.so
/usr/lib/perl5/nginx.pm
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/nginx
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/nginx-extras
/usr/share/doc/nginx-extras/copyright
/usr/share/doc/nginx-extras/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/nginx-extras/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/nginx-extras/CHANGES.gz
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `dpkg --list | grep -i nginx` ?

Comment: just added the package list

Comment: Okay, looks like you have the proper package installed. I'm out of ideas, sorry!

Comment: Can you run `dpkg --listfiles nginx-extras` and check if there is any upload-module related files?

Comment: pkhamre, I added the listing. There seems to be no uplod related file there.

Comment: Okay, it is probably just compiled into the `nginx` binary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx upload module has been removed from Debian package/s, as of this writing. Ref: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729003

Whenever you post the output of `nginx -V`, please consider formatting it. I use

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | sed 's,--,\n--,g'
```

to format its output. There are other ways to format too, such as a few mentioned at https://serverfault.com/a/472513/102173 .

Comment: I see. So how can I downgrade nginx to 1.2.1 to be able to use the module?

Comment: I always compile Nginx from source and I have never used backports. So, I don't know how to go back. May be you could put it as a separate question in ServerFault.

Comment: BTW, here's my script to compile from source. https://github.com/pothi/WordPress-Nginx/blob/master/nginx-compile-from-source.sh Please note that it is **not** tested on Debian 6, but tested with Debian 7!

Comment: First link appears broken. Here's another: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729003

Comment: Thanks @iX3 . The link is updated.