# How to downgrade nginx on Debian?

Tags: nginx, debian-squeeze, downgrade

Since file upload module exited in nginx 1.2.1 but [omitted](https://serverfault.com/questions/544214/how-to-add-nginx-file-upload-module-to-debian-squeeze) since 1.3.x, I'd like to downgrade  current nginx 1.4.2 on Debian squeeze to 1.2.1, so that I can easily have the module. I am wondering what is the easiest wat to do the downgrade. Also I'd like to know whether it would have some serious security drawbacks and hence not advised.

Answer (score 2):

a similar question, [How can I install apache with a specific version?](https://serverfault.com/questions/544779/how-can-i-install-apache-with-a-specific-version)

here's the copypasta:

---

You need to do the following:

> apt-cache showpkg

The above command will display list of available versions for this package. Then select the needed version and do the following.

```
apt-get install <packagename>=<complete version name>
```

Example:

```
apt-cache showpkg apache2
apt-get install apache2=2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two medium vulnerabilities for 1.2.1. I would advise against it.
Source: http://nginx.org/en/security_advisories.html